# Periodically sync local folders using rsync (no symlinks!)

Tags: backup, rsync, startup, synchronization

I am using Dropbox to have an online backup of some data. However I want to encrypt my data before uploading it to Dropbox. Therefore I have created a TrueCrypt container and I am using `rsync` to synchronize the original data with the data in the TrueCrypt container. The reason for this duplicative setup is because I want both **hassle-free local access** and an **encrypted online backup**.

However now on to my question. I wrote a script which uses rsync for the local synchronisation. I however do not want to execute it manually. Could someone tell me how I can run the script, say every 30 seconds, from the moment I login to my computer?

ps: I could always embed the current code of my script in a never-ending `while loop` and add `sleep 30`. However are there other more sophisticated ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a cron job. Most cron daemons do not allow second resolution, but you could run a job every minute as root using something like the following in `/etc/cron.d/encrypted-backup` (assuming you want to run as root):

```
* * * * * root rsync [...]
```